# Seeking explanation of some clojure special forms and metadata

Tags: clojure

I am fairly new to clojure and I am going through various code challenges/exercises, as well as the general APIs.

I understand the convention of naming dynamic variables with * at both ends of the symbol

`eg: *myvar*` ..

I also understand the application of the caret symbol, for example on a dynamic variable

`eg: ^:dynamic` ..

But I am confused by the convention of sometimes having a symbol/variable end with a *, but not start with a * ..

`eg:  list*`.

The following are some other metadata forms I am finding confusing .. I understand they provide additional information for macros and special forms .. But, when would you use which and how?  ..

```
^Type → ^{:tag Type}
^:key → ^{:key true}
^:private
^{:once true}
```

Any explanations or links with clear explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: [`list*` is not new to Lisp](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node149.html), but frankly I don't think the * on the end follows any convention. All the other forms that end in * behave like [`let*`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node83.html), which is the same as the default `let` behavior in Clojure.

Comment: @DaoWen, thanks for the input .. and what you state (ie, no difference between `list` and `list*` ) is what is adding to my confusion.  I have since come across [this blog](http://yobriefca.se/blog/2014/05/19/the-weird-and-wonderful-characters-of-clojure/) and most of the special characters are explained there .. but none for `list*` though.

Comment: I didn't say there's no difference between `list` and `list*`, but rather that adding `*` on the end doesn't seem to have a consistent meaning. `list*` is like `list`, but it takes another list as its last argument (so it just `cons`es all the arguments but the last onto the last).

Comment: Yeah, you are indeed right.  This wasn't obvious to me previously. I just used doc and source to see the difference between list and list*.  I should get into the habit of using doc/source more often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Clojure, it's common for the *internal* version of a function (or macro) to end in `*`: the non-* version is the *public* one that users should call. Sometimes that's a macro that provides custom syntax around the internal function.

An extreme case of this occurs in the Clojure core library, where several forms (`fn*`, `let*`, etc) bottom out as special forms that are understood and implemented in the compiler itself. It's merely a convention that their names end in `*`.

The meta tags you mention at the end are described at http://clojure.org/metadata.

- The `^Type` form is used to provide a type-hint for the type of the next
  form: this is used to avoid reflection when compiling a Java interop
  call where the type is ambiguous. More here:
  http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints
- The `^:key` form is used to supply a variety of boolean
  flags - for example `^:dynamic` marks dynamic vars. See
  http://clojure.org/vars
- The `^:private` form prevents a symbol from being listed in the public
  symbols for a namespace (although it is still available for lookup
  and dereferencing as a Var: #'foo. More here:
  http://clojure.org/special_forms
- The `^{:once true}` is a bit of metadata the compiler can use to avoid
  retaining an intermediate object for garbage collection (see
  [here](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2013/09/11/macros-closures-and-unexpected-object-retention/) for more detail). This is an advanced
  optimization and something you should rarely worry about.

Comment: that's a comprehensive coverage, along with the links to further information.  Thanks a million.  Will accept this as an answer.